# Ffmpeg decode H264 video from RTP stream very slow

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have H264 RTP stream over network and I need to decode it. I use libx264 to encode stream and ffmpeg to decode. When I connect  to server using VLC, it correct play video without any problem. But when I connect to server using my application I have a long period, when widget, which draw video from this stream, draw only one image.

I check log file and found, that avcodec_decode_video2() set got_image into 1 very rarely! Decoder give me new decoded frame average every 1-2 seconds, but on the server I have 12-15 fps on encoder!

What the reasons of this delays on decoder and how I can fix its?

```
avcodec_register_all();
av_init_packet(&m_packet);
m_decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!m_decoder)
{
    QString str = QString("Can't find H264 decoder!");
    emit criticalError(str);
}
m_decoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_decoder);

m_decoderContext->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_LOW_DELAY;
m_decoderContext->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;
AVDictionary* dictionary = nullptr;
if (avcodec_open2(m_decoderContext, m_decoder, &dictionary) < 0)
{
    QString str = QString("Failed to open decoder!");
    emit criticalError(str);
}
qDebug() << "H264 Decoder successfully opened";
m_picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
...
    while(m_packet.size > 0)
    {
        int got_picture;
        int len = avcodec_decode_video2(m_decoderContext, m_picture, &got_picture, &m_packet);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            QString err("Decoding error");
            qDebug() << err;
            //emit criticalError(err);
            return false;
        }
        if (got_picture)
        {
                //create from frame QImage and send it into GUI thread
            qDebug() << "H264Decoder: frame decoded!";
```

I try to change some options of m_decoderContext (i.e. thread_count) but this not changing anything.

Comment: I fix this problem. I change encoder's setting and set i_keyint_max=5 and b_intra_refresh=0 in x264_param_t

Comment: Where did you change these parameters?